# Error 1064 when COUNTING DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

My query statement

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT name) 
FROM facebook.users
```

results to

> mysql.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '\xef\xbb\xbfSELECT Count(DISTINCT name)
>   \r\nFROM facebook.users' at line 1")

How do I fix this, thanks

Comment: Whatever your SQL client is, it doesn't support UTF-8 files with BOM. Just check your editor settings and get rid of the BOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check how you pass your query. `\xef\xbb\xbf` is [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding).

> The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the (hexadecimal) byte sequence 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT name) FROM facebook.users
-- query is correct
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew my basic query was correct.  My problem was in the .sql file I was using. I copied the query to a text file then save as a .sql file and it worked.